# Sheaves on basic open sets of an affine scheme, confused about Vakil's notes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

I thought I was generally getting my head around the sheaf structure defined by basic open sets for an affine scheme, but a line of a proof in Ravi Vakil's notes found 
[here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec2915public.pdf) (page 130) has me confused. So for a ring $A$ with $s \in A$, $s$ defines a global section of the structure sheaf on $\text{spec}A$ given by taking $s \pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$. To show the identifying property for the structure sheaf, Vakil supposes that the restriction of $s$ to a basic open set, $D(f)$, is $0$. That is, he assumes,
$$ \text{res}_{\text{specA}, D(f)}s = 0. $$
He then concludes that this means that there is some integer $m$ such that $f^{m}s = 0$. I am confused about why he draws this conclusion. My reasoning was as follows:

If $s$ is zero on the restriction to $D(f)$, then it means that every prime ideal not containing $f$ must contain $s$. This is equivalent to saying that every prime ideal contains $fs$. In other words, $fs$ is the zero function on $\text{spec}A$. In other words again, $fs$ is in the nilradical. But then why does Vakil say that there is an $m$ such that $f^{m}s = 0$? If he meant $fs$ as an element of $A$, then surely he means $(fs)^{m} = 0$, and if he was talking about $fs$ as a global section, then he meant $fs = 0$ as a function. So why $f^{m}s = 0$? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: $D (f) = \operatorname{Spec} A_f$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just the definition of equality in the localization.  Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring and $S \subseteq A$ is a multiplicative set.  If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ in $S^{-1}A$, then there exists $s \in S$ such that $s(ad - bc) = 0$.  Now let $S = \{f^m : m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\}$, $b = d = 1$ and $c = 0$:
$$
\frac{a}{1} = \frac{0}{1} \implies 0= f^m(a - 0) = f^m a
$$
for some $m$.

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with localization. Saying that the restriction is zero means that $s$ is zero in the ring $A_f$. And by the definition of localization this is equivalent to $f^ms=0$.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers explain why Vakil is correct, but neither explains where you went wrong.

A function is not determined by its value at the points of a space. For example, $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2))$, the section $x$ is nonzero even though it vanishes at each prime in the ring.

Thus your first if and only if, that $s$ is zero if and only if it vanishes at each prime, is incorrect.

Comment: In that case, would my reasoning be correct in the case of an integral domain, where the nilradical is trivial? Surely then the only such functions would actually be zero?

Comment: Indeed, in that case (assuming $f \neq 0$), one certainly has $f^ms = 0$ for some $m$ if and only if $(fs)^m = 0$ for some $m$ (if and only if $s = 0$).